# Trying to find specific children's horror-themed board game in book format

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to find this game I had as a kid.

It was a roughly A3-sized cardboard book that contained several spooky-themed game boards. Each page was a different board and theme. I can't remember exactly but I'm pretty sure there was vampires, ghosts, skeletons, graveyard, etc. They were very basic, snakes and ladders-type boards.

On the last page of the book, there was a spinner and there were cutouts on each of the other pages so you could access it. I don't remember there being any game pieces that came with it as it was just a book.

This would have been the late 1990s - early 2000s and I am from Australia so it could be limited to that region.

I can't find any reference to it or anything similar in a book format.

Please help!